# SQLCHAR (or SQL functions) inconsistent between projects

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio, types

I am using Visual Studio for a project, and in a specific one I needed to use some sql functions, for some reason it was fine with the type `SQLCHAR*` and not `SQLWCHAR*`. I then copied the project over because it has some GUI setup and window handling, but I came across errors only related to this. Basically, each error is telling me that the function cannot convert a `SQLCHAR*` to `SQLWCHAR*`, so I imagine the function signature is different somehow. This seems really odd to me because it is the exact same source code, nothing has changed, same build (x86).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main()
{
    const char* m_Path = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=Database.accdb;";
    HENV m_Environment = nullptr;
    HDBC m_Connection = nullptr;
    HSTMT m_QueryStatement = nullptr;
    RETCODE m_ReturnStatus = 0;


    m_ReturnStatus = SQLAllocEnv(&m_Environment);
    m_ReturnStatus = SQLAllocConnect(m_Environment, &m_Connection);
    m_ReturnStatus = SQLDriverConnect(m_Connection, nullptr, m_Path, SQL_NTS, nullptr, 0, nullptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

    SQLDisconnect(m_Connection);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_Connection);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_Environment);

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "SQLWCHAR *" test    

C2664   'SQLRETURN SQLDriverConnectW(SQLHDBC,SQLHWND,SQLWCHAR *,SQLSMALLINT,SQLWCHAR *,SQLSMALLINT,SQLSMALLINT *,SQLUSMALLINT)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'const char *' to 'SQLWCHAR *'  test
```

Edit:
Using Visual Studio's `ctrl + click`, on the project that it works with, it opens up `sqlext.h` when I click on a specific function, but on the project it doesn't work on, when I `ctrl + click` on the same function, it opens up `sqlucode.h` for some reason.

Comment: Which API function ? At a guess the old project did not have `UNICODE` defined and the new one does.  Defining `UNICODE` will auto select the wide functions.  Please post the code in question together with the complete error message.  Most Windows functions of the form `AWindowsFunction` are macros that expand to either: `AWindowsFunctionA` or `AWindowsFunctionW` and change their parameter types, depending if `UNICODE` is defined or not.

Comment: @RichardCritten in advanced settings, both say Unicode character set. Also I updated the question with some code.

Comment: What the exact error message(s) please? See [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: @RichardCritten I added that

Comment: Note the `W` on the end of `SQLDriverConnectW`

Comment: @RichardCritten That seems so weird to me because that isn't even the function I am using.

Comment: See my 1st comment

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't know how to enable or disable UNICODE, in the other project there is no #define's written by me, nor is there in this one. If I go project properties > Configuration > Advanced, there is `Use Unicode Character Set` for both projects.

Comment: @RichardCritten I set that to `Not Set` and that fixed it, thanks for pointing me in that direction. Can you write an answer so I can tick it? Side note though, It seems extremely odd to me that the other project has unicode enabled, yet it still works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By @RichardCritten, Go to Project `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `Advanced` > `Character Set` > `Not Set`

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.